# bash infinite loop over 3 values

Tags: bash, for-loop, infinite-loop

I have 3 static values: `aa`, `bb`, `cc`. I want to loop over them indefinitely with exit case.
Writing the simple loop is easy:

```sh
for i in aa bb cc; do 
   echo $i
done
```

But I want to loop over them indefinitely until some condition is meat:

```sh
for i in aa bb cc; do 
   echo $i
   if [ somecondition ]; then
      doSomething
      break
   fi
done
```

The `somecondition` depends on external conditions and on `i`. It should look like try to do something with `i` until success.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to nest your code inside an infinite loop:

```
while true; do
    for i in aa bb cc; do
        echo $i;
        if [ somecondition ]; then
            doSomething
            break 2
        fi
    done
done
```

Notice that the `break` command now has an argument `2`.

`man bash` says:

```
    break [n]
        Exit from within a for, while, until, or  select
        loop.   If  n  is  specified, break n levels.  n
        must be >= 1.  If n is greater than  the  number
        of  enclosing  loops,  all  enclosing  loops are
        exited.  The return value is 0 unless n  is  not
        greater than or equal to 1.
```